# How do I get a variety of transition mode types in my JSSOR slide show?

Tags: jssor

I am building a pretty good JSSOR slide show, with what must be recognized as very good  support by jssor on StackOverflow. I'm also completely amazed that the best slideshow program in the world is free.

My slideshow does a "chess mode" type animation mode on every slide. What I am looking for is a variety of transition modes (I call them transition modes, but maybe that is the wrong term?).

Example:
["ChessMode" slide show](http://webanautics.com/slideshow/slideshow2.html)

But I want something more like this:
[JSSOR image-gallery demo](http://www.jssor.com/demos/image-gallery.html)

I think the secret lies in the _SlideshowTransitions array values, but I don't know what the full range of possibilities are, or how to make multiple effects modes within one slide show.

These are my _SlideshowTransitions settings:

```
var _SlideshowTransitions = [{
        $Duration: 600,
        $Delay: 50,
        $Cols: 8,
        $Rows: 4,
        $FlyDirection: 5,
        $Formation:
        $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationZigZag,
        $Assembly: 1028,
        $ChessMode: { $Column: 3, $Row: 12 },
        $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad },
        $Opacity: 2
    }];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you use only one transition, please use more transitions in following manner,

```
var _SlideshowTransitions = [
{ code1 },
{ code2 },
{ code3 },
...
];
```

Get transition code at http://www.jssor.com/development/tool-slideshow-transition-viewer.html